# Why does .equals() not working

Tags: java, string, replace, equals

I printed 2 strings and they are literally identical, no whitespaces cause i replaced them.
https://ideone.com/cw07LG 
Here it is compiled

```
 public class Palindrome{
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){
        int length;
        String oppositeWord ="";
        word = word.replace(" ","");
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        length = word.length();

        for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))){
                oppositeWord +=word.charAt(i);
            }else{
                word = word.replace(word.charAt(i),'\0');
            }

        }
        System.out.println(oppositeWord);
        System.out.println(word);

        return oppositeWord.equals(word);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("Madam, I'm Adam"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you mutating `word`?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Not answering your question here, but I wouldn't make a reverse of the word and compare it. Just compare the 1st letter with the last letter, then the 2nd letter with the 2nd last letter and so on.

Comment: They're not the same... oppositeword is `madamimadam`, where as word is `madam i madam`

Comment: The punctuation is making it weird.. Try simpler cases like `"abcba"` before you worry that stuff is broken

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, sorry for the noob question.

Comment: @QBrute the first thing he does is strip out spaces

Comment: @TedBigham I copied his code and ran it in Eclipse. That was the output. It probably has to do something with the 0-byte he's using.

Comment: @QBrute i did too, and the spaces are not there

Comment: I think this line of code `word = word.replace(word.charAt(i),'\0');` made a few people here blood boil.

Comment: @TedBigham Hm, that's weird. Why are they showing in my instance?

Comment: @QBrute I see. your eclipse console must be printing the \0 as a space. Try running from the command line.

Comment: SCNR: another palindrome http://xkcd.com/1632/

Answer (score 1):

First, Java Strings are immutable and should not be manipulated character by character (that is why the Java Library has the StringBuilder and StringBuffer classes).

Second, Java Strings are not really equivalent to `char[]` in C/C++. They are more like `char*` in that they point to some other memory that holds the actual information. Changing the non-alphabetic characters to `'\0'` null characters is not deleting them from the string. They are not printed on the screen, but still exist in memory. (That is one way Java Strings are different from C/C++ strings ... Java Strings are not null terminated arrays of characters!)

If you add some print statements to print the length, you will find that the `oppositeWord` is two characters smaller than `word`.

```
System.out.println(oppositeWord.length()); // prints  11
System.out.println(word.length());         // prints  13
```

To really make the two Strings equal, the same characters replaced in `word` must also be inserted in `oppositeWord` at the same indices or removed altogether from both. i.e.

```
for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    if(Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))) {
        oppositeWord +=word.charAt(i);
    } else {
        word = word.replace(word.charAt(i),'\0');
        oppositeWord += word.charAt(i); // << This line!
    }
}
```

Now, both Strings will contain the same information and `oppositeWord.equals(word)` will hold.

Also FYI, `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` both have `reverse()` methods that could be used to simplify this process.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a character with '\0' is not the same thing as removing the character all together.  It won't show up when you print it, so they will look the same, but it's still there and will make them not equal.

Try printing the lengths along with the words.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
word = word.replace(word.charAt(i),'\0');
```

Replacing a character by `\0` isn't the same as removing it. You want something like this:

```
word = word.replace(""+word.charAt(i), "");
```

However, like this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211602/what-does-equals-not-work#comment58138509_35211602) says, there are better ways to check if a word is a palindrome.

Also, I'm not sure why, but your ideone.com shows a different output from my IDE (NetBeans). Yours shows:

```
madamimadam
madamimadam
false
```

But as [Qbrute points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211602/what-does-equals-not-work/35211728#comment58138516_35211602), the output is:

```
madamimadam
madam  i  madam
false
```

Which explains why the result is `false`. My best guess is that your on-line IDE has some trouble converting the `\0` you added into text and just doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is true as mentioned by bluemoon93 that the two strings are actually not equal. The original string is madam i madam. This means it consists of spaces that makes the two strings different. I would suggest that you remove punctuation, spaces from the original string using regex. This will remove any extra spaces or punctuation.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String word){
    int length;
    String oppositeWord ="";

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    length = word.length();

    String newword = word.replaceAll("[\\s\\p{Punct}]", "");

    for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))){
            oppositeWord +=word.charAt(i);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(oppositeWord);
    System.out.println(newword);

    return oppositeWord.equals(newword);

}
```

The return result will now return true, since both strings are equal as they are matched by valid character and do not  contain space or punctuation.